# External Modules to be included in Gitlab Yaml File

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci, importerror, cicd, cythonize

I have three .pyx files, *one.pyx*, *two.pyx*, *main.pyx*. I **cythonize *one.pyx***, to get *one.pyd*, and then **cimport one** to *two.pyx*. I then **cythonize *two.pyx***, then **cimport one** and **cimport two** to *main.pyx*. In this way, I am able to access functions from *one.pyx* and *two.pyx*.

I then attempt to **cython *main.pyx*** to get *main.c*, and then compile *main.c* using **gcc**, to get main.exe. When I run this file locally, it works. But, as I try to use *.gitlab-ci.yml*, it fails and shows that there is no module one in *main.pyx* file, even though I try to run *main.exe*.

--

*one.pyx*

```
function()
```

--

**cythonize -i *one.pyx***

--

*two.pyx*

```
cimport one

one.function()
function2()
```

--

**cythonize -i *two.pyx***

--

*main.pyx*

```
cimport one
cimport two

one.function()
two.function2()
```

--

**cython *main.pyx* --embed**

--

**gcc -I/path/to/includes *main.c* -o *main***

--

***main***

(Works fine)

--

*.gitlab-ci.yml*

```
stages:

- build
- test

image: python:3.9.16

before_script:

- apt-get clean
- apt-get --allow-unauthenticated update
- apt-get upgrade
- apt-get install -y gcc
- apt-get update
- apt-get install libexpat1-dev
- apt search '^python\[0-9\]\*-dev'
- python3 --version

build-job:  
stage: build
script:
- echo "Compiling the code..."
- gcc -v -DSIZEOF_VOID=8 -DMS_WIN64 main.c -I /path/to/includes-lpython3.9 -o main
- echo "Compile complete."
artifacts:
paths:
- main

test-test-job:
stage: test
script:
- echo "Running tests."
- ./main
- echo "Code coverage is 90%"
```

--

Error message for test-test-job:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.pyx", line 1, in init main
cimport two
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'one'
```

I am unsure how to resolve this as I am new to Gitlab Yaml files and cython. I have tried changing the import statements, and all, but I think it is not able to recognize the two .pyd files.